# Ternary Operator Javascript in Else case Do Nothing

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am making a service call having 3 parameters based on IF condition else setting 5 parameters. Need to use Ternary operator to set 4th parameter. Else do not set anything.
Below is the code

```
if (allow) {
   return forkJoin(param1, param2, param3) // Here i need to set param4 based on other condition
} else {
   return forkJoin(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5)
}
```

I am trying to set using below

```
if (allow) {
   return forkJoin(param1, param2, this.vipPerson ? param4 : null, param3)
   // But using ternary operator i cant send NULL if this.vipPerson is False. What to do so that 
   // if vipPerson is TRUE it should be like this
   return forkJoin(param1, param2, param3, param4)
   // Else it should be like this 
   return forkJoin(param1, param2, param3)
}
```

I cant send NULL. Finding the way to send nothing in case if its False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more declarative way would be to define the two possible observables, then use the `iif()` operator to run the condition. While it's not exactly ternary, it's as close as any RxJS operator gets.

```
const basic$ = forkJoin(param1, param2, param3);
const vip$ = forkJoin(param1, param2, param3, param4);

return iif(()=>this.vipPerson, vip$, basic$)
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/iif

Comment: Thanks marking it as answer it worked for me as required..
If possible can you also comment once how to do exactly the same without using RxJs

Comment: You could also use a ternary expression to declare the response `return !!this.vipPerson ? vip$ : basic$`

Answer (score 1):

forkJoin takes array of observables, null is not observable. change it to :-

```
of(null)
```

you need to import of from rxjs.

Comment: I cant send NULL. Finding the way to send nothing in case if its False

Comment: then send EMPTY, import EMPTY from rxjs.